# Отображение изображения после задержки

Tags: delphi

```
begin
Image1.Show;
Sleep(2000);
Image2.Show
end;
```

Такая процедура стоит на клике на `button`. `Image1` и `image2` наложены на форме друг на друга, и `visible:false` в обеих... При клике на `button` должно показать первое, а через 2 секунды второе изображение, но показывает оба изображения сразу, при чем после 2 секунд задержки. В чем ошибка этого кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может надо так?

```
begin
Image1.Show;
Form1.update;
Sleep(2000);
Image2.Show;
Form1.update;
end;
```

Comment: простите если тупые вопросы задаю, но что это изменило?
зделал как вы сказали, результат тот же

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: Да, так работает. Доволен как слон) а вы случайно не знаете, почему предыдущий код не работал?

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, то когда вы делаете `Image1.Show` посылается асинхронное событие `update` форме, а из-за sleep - блокируется поток и оно обрабатывается в самом конце, сдесь-же мы его в ручную вызываем.

Comment: Не, там ничего не блокируется, просто сообщения отправляются по завершению потока) Т.е. если где-то перед Sleep(2000) поставить `Form.Close;`, картинка прорисуется сразу, а закроется форма через 2 сек.

Comment: тоесть если нету апдейта формы или Application.ProcessMessages, то на форме отобразится только конечный результат действия процедуры?

Comment: Да. Но еще учитывайте, что Update занимается *только* перерисовкой. Хотя в вашем случае он мне кажется более подходящим, да.

Comment: еще один вопрос, но не в тему, просто некуда больше писать. Здесь есть приватные сообщения?

Comment: @КомРом, нет, здесь нет приватов. Кто может/хочет общаться вне хэшкода - у тех в профиле контакты указаны.

Answer (score 2):

```
Image1.Show;
Application.ProcessMessages;
Sleep(2000);
Image2.Show;
```

Для показа/скрытия в одном потоке необходимо перерисовывать форму.

Comment: спасибо большое! не подскажите где я могу прочитать о даном операторе? Application.ProcessMessages;

Comment: Первая же <a href="http://www.delphi-manual.ru/processmessages.php">ссылка</a> в гугле) Обновленный ответ @timka_s тоже верный, кстати, но ProcessMessages работает вне форм и используется не только для перерисовки, а еще всяких операций с потоками и подобным.

Comment: ну тогда еще один вопрос)
PaintBox1.Canvas.MoveTo(10,10);
PaintBox1.Canvas.LineTo(20,20);
Sleep(1000);
PaintBox1.Canvas.LineTo(30,20);
почему здесь работает без processmessages?

Comment: Ммм, могу только поугадывать, что обновление `Canvas`'а само по себе вызывает перерисовку (но даю 80%, что только `Canva`s'a). Т.е. тот же `Image.Show` может не сработать.

Answer (score 1):

В чём именно ошибка не знаю: у меня этот код тоже не сработал, точнее сработал, но точно также. Вот получилось что-то подобное по таймеру сделать.

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  t: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  t:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Visible:=True;
  Inc(t);
  If (t=2) Then
    Begin
      Timer1.Enabled:=False;
      Image1.Visible:=False;
      Image2.Visible:=True;
    End;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=True;
end;
```

Comment: Да через таймер делать можно, но код в разы больше, а если делать большую програму, то очень не выгодно таким способом

Comment: Inc(t) нужен для увеличения t на единицу, чтобы можно было отследить сколько шагов проделал таймер, и на нужном шаге выключить его.

Comment: а если вместо оператора inc(t) использовать просто t:=t+1, в чем разница?

Comment: В этом случае разницы нет, просто функция Inc() имеет 2 параметра, второй из которых - инкремент (по умолчанию равен 1), т. е. запись Inc(t, 2) будет эквивалентна t:=t+2, функция, на мой взгляд, просто выглядит красивее, хотя сам долго к ней привыкал.

Comment: раз уж вы еще здесь, может ответите на мой комментарий к ответу выше? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
begin

Image1.Visible := true;

sleep(2000);

Image1.Visible := false;

Image2.Visible := true;

end;
```